# Elasticsearch custom analyzer with ngram and without word delimiter on hyphens

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analysis, analyzer

I am trying to index strings that contain hyphens but do not contain spaces, periods or any other punctuation. I do not want to split up the words based on hyphens, instead I would like to have the hyphens be part of the indexed text.

For example, my 6 text strings would be:

- magazineplayon
- magazineofhorses
- online-magazine
- best-magazine
- friend-of-magazines
- magazineplaygames

I would like to be able to search these string for the **text containing "play"** or for the **text starting with "magazine"**.

I have been able to use **ngram** to make the text containing "play" work properly. However, the hyphen is causing text to split and it is including results where "magazine" is in the word after a hyphen. I only want words starting at the beginning of the string with "magazine" to appear.

Based on the sample above, only these 3 should appear when beginning with "magazine":

- magazineplayon
- magazineofhorses
- magazineplaygames

Please help with my ElasticSearch Index Sample:

```
DELETE /sample

PUT /sample
{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_shards":5,
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "nGram_filter": {
                   "type": "nGram",
                   "min_gram": 2,
                   "max_gram": 20,
                   "token_chars": [
                      "letter",
                      "digit"
                   ]
                },
                "word_delimiter_filter": {
                    "type": "word_delimiter",
                    "preserve_original": true,
                    "catenate_all" : true
                }
             },
          "analyzer": {
            "ngram_index_analyzer": {
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer": "lowercase",
              "filter" : ["nGram_filter", "word_delimiter_filter"]
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
PUT /sample/1/_create
{
    "name" : "magazineplayon"
}
PUT /sample/3/_create
{
    "name" : "magazineofhorses"
}
PUT /sample/4/_create
{
    "name" : "online-magazine"
}
PUT /sample/5/_create
{
    "name" : "best-magazine"
}
PUT /sample/6/_create
{
    "name" : "friend-of-magazines"
}
PUT /sample/7/_create
{
    "name" : "magazineplaygames"
}

GET /sample/_search
{
"query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "name": "*play*" 
        }
    }
}

GET /sample/_search
{
"query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "name": "magazine*" 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
I updated all my create statements to use TEST after sample:

```
PUT /sample/test/7/_create
{
    "name" : "magazinefairplay"
}
```

I then ran the following command to return only names that had the word "play" in them instead of doing the wildcard search. This worked correctly and returned only two records.

```
POST /sample/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
                {"match": { "name.substrings": "play" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the following command to return only names that started with "magazine". My expectation was that "online-magazine", "best-magazine" and "friend-of-magazines" would not appear. However, all seven records were returned including these three.

```
POST /sample/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
                {"match": { "name.prefixes": "magazine" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to filter out the prefix where the hyphen is used?

Comment: I tried using the prefix command as part of the search, instead of wildcard, but this did not help.  <br/>      <br/>       `GET /sample/_search
{ "query": {
    "prefix" : { "name" :  "magazine" }
  }
}
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right path, however, you need to also add another analyzer that leverages the [`edge-ngram` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) in order to make the "starts with" contraint work. You can keep the `ngram` for checking fields that "contain" a given word, but you need `edge-ngram` to check that a field "starts with" some token.

```
PUT /sample
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 5,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "nGram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        },
        "edgenGram_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "nGram_filter"
          ]
        },
        "edge_ngram_index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "edgenGram_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "prefixes": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "edge_ngram_index_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "substrings": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "ngram_index_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then your query will become (i.e. search for all documents whose `name` field contains `play` or starts with `magazine`)

```
POST /sample/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
                {"match": { "name.substrings": "play" }},
                {"match": { "name.prefixes": "magazine" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note: don't use `wildcard` for searching for substrings, as it will kill the performance of your cluster (more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html))

Comment: **Update 1** I tried the suggestion above, but I got all 7 records back. I posted the command I tried to use above.

Comment: Good catch,. I've removed the word delimiter filter, which was causing issues, also I change the tokenizer. Please try again