# How to increase performance using wildcard *word*?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, wildcard

I use wildcard query someting like : *someWord* executing time for 5 000 000 docs is almost 26 seconds what can I do to increase performance?

Comment: Never use a wildcard query for searching infixed tokens. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43454417/4604579 (hint: use ngrams)